# gnuplot - Automatic data conversion from 2D to matrix

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I'm trying to draw heatmap for my dataset.

Dataset consists of x, y values like following.

```
x1, y1
x2, y2
x3, y3
...
```

I only can plot statistical dispersion from my dataset. 
Because Heatmap requires matrix for plotting.

Is there any convenient way of converting 2D dataset of mine to Matrix by auto selecting X range and Y range in gnuplot(or manual way of selecting range)?

Like this one of auto selected range and each count in that range,

```
   ?      x_range0    x_range1    x_range2    ..
y_range0     3           4          5
y_range1     2           1          6
y_range2     1           6          6
   ..
```

Comment: Please `dput()` the sample data and provide the code you used in your attempt

Comment: Putting 3 different language tags might seem to be a promising strategy to get an answer, but if all you have done is create a sketchy problem description it will appear that you just posting a "Haz te code" question and many of us think these should be closed.

Comment: @42- Ah, sorry. I changed tag only on gnuplot. What I had trouble with is that finding any function which make ease of the task I want to achieve.